# What do the SchemaAutoAction values mean?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm getting back into NHibernate and I've noticed a new configuration property being used in examples: SchemaAutoAction.  I cant seem to find documentation on what the various settings mean.  The settings / my guesses as to what they mean are:

- Recreate -- Drop and recreate the schema every time
- Create -- If the schema does not exist create it
- Update -- issue alter statements to make the existing schema match
  the model
- Validate -- Blow up if the schema differs from the model

Is this correct?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what `update` does but the other three look about right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SchemaAutoAction` is the same as `schema-action` mapping attribute.

As per docs:

> The new 'schema-action' is set to none, this will prevent NHibernate
>   from including this mapping in its schema export, it would otherwise
>   attempt to create a table for this view

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but not quite. The SchemaAutoAction is analogous to the configuration property hbm2ddl.auto, and its values are:

Create: always create the database when a session factory is created;
Validate: when a session factory is created check if the database matches the mappings and throw an exception otherwise;
Update: when a session factory is created issues DDL commands to update the database if it doesn't match the mappings;
Recreate: always creates the database and drop it when the session factory is disposed.